# Real-time image slicing for Deep Zoom and Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, image-processing, silverlight-4.0, deepzoom

Is there an example where the Deep Zoom images will prepare dynamically in real time? Is it even possible with Silverlight 4? So basically, whatever the Deep Zoom composer is doing under the hood should happen in real-time, on demand...

Comment: If you already have the full image available in Silverlight in order to slice it why would you want to?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to generate deep zoom files on the fly. 
Obviously, this has to happen on the server-side, for the client-side Silverlight app to consume it.

The google keywords you're looking for is "deep zoom batch" or "deep zoom export" or "DeepZoomTools.dll".

This is not an officially supported scenario (afaik), but it is definitely possible. 
The more recent the blog post, the more likely you are to get this to work.

Here are some blog posts that have worked for me at one point or another:
[Deep Zoom Batch Processing using DeepZoomTools.dll](http://johnlivingstontech.blogspot.com/2009/06/deep-zoom-batch-processing-using.html)
[Deep Zoom Batch Export using C# - Update](http://blogs.msdn.com/giorgio/archive/2008/08/26/deep-zoom-batch-export-using-c-update.aspx)
[Deep Zoom Image Generation with DeepZoomTools.DLL](http://bryantlikes.com/DeepZoomImageGenerationWithDeepZoomToolsDLL.aspx)